# could not initialize proxy - no Session on getValue from java object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have simple hibernate entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SomeTable")
public class SomeEntity{

@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "sme_entity_ID", unique = true, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
@Id
@Getter @Setter private UUID entityId;

@Column(name="some_field_name")
@Getter @Setter private String someFiled;
```

And method in repository implementation

```
@Override
@Transactional
public SomeEntity getSomeEntity(UUID someEntityId) {
    return (SomeEntity) getSession().load(SomeEntity.class, someEntityId);
}
```

When there is no entity in DB, i want to throw exception in service. When I send request to get non-existing entity it returns `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.`

```
SomeEntity  someEntity = entityRepository.getSomeEntity(someEntityID);
```

In this case someEntity is an object with null fields. And when I try to get some field from this object (to check if it is null), this exception is thrown: `could not initialize proxy - no Session` 
Why this exception is thrown on just getting value from POJO object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Session.load()` always return a “proxy” (Hibernate term) without hitting the database. In Hibernate, proxy is an object with the given identifier value, its properties are not initialized yet, it just look like a temporary fake object.